# How do I check for 2 keywords in PHP

Tags: php, sql, session

I want to check for my session. The code below works:

```
if ($_SESSION["rol"] != 'trainer') {
}
```

But this code doesnt work:

```
if ($_SESSION["rol"] != 'trainer' || 'commandant') {
}
```

It should check for both, because both have permission. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It should be `if ($_SESSION["rol"] != 'trainer' || $_SESSION["rol"] !=  'commandant') {
}`

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile I don't think so

Comment: Makes most sense to use http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php in situations like this, especially if this list could possibly be extended in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
if ($_SESSION["rol"] != 'trainer' || $_SESSION["rol"] != 'commandant') {

}
```

Comment: When the condition will be false?

Answer (score 1):

```
$role = ['trainer','commandant'];

if(!in_array($_SESSION['rol'],$role))
{
 //do some stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I will probably do the following, where the `isset` ensures the key exists (and helps reduce warnings when the key is not available):

```
if (isset($_SESSION["rol"]) && ($_SESSION["rol"] != 'trainer' || $_SESSION["rol"] == 'commandant')) {
    echo 'do some...';
}
```

`array_key_exists` is a nice alternative to using `isset` to check for keys:

```
if (array_key_exists('rol', $_SESSION) && ($_SESSION["rol"] != 'trainer' || $_SESSION["rol"] == 
'commandant')) {
    echo 'do more...';
}
```

Hope that helps.

PS: @dexter solution with a `in_array()` will be better over time and easier to maintain.